# React: добавить класс по клику

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Имею следующий код:

```
export default function TaskList(){

    const[data, setData] = useState([]);
    const[expand, setExpand] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/dash/task_list')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => setData(json));

    },[]);
    console.log(data)
    return(
        <div className='segments'>
                {
                    data.map((task, index) => (
                        <div onClick={() => setExpand(!expand)} className={`segment ${expand ? 'active' : ''}`}>
                            <a className='header'>{task.task_id}</a>
                            <div className='description'>{task.event_time}</div>
                        </div>
                    ))
                }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Пытаюсь добавить стиль по нажатию `segment`, на данный момент получается что класс `active` добавляется ко всем итемам в списке, в чем ошибка? мне нужно чтобы применялся только к тому итему на котором был клик

Comment: Вынести логику клика в мап

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас общее состояние для всех элементов.
Если `expand` - `true`, то ВСЕ элементы с классом `active`

Вы можете

1. или создать отдельный компонент `Segment`, который будет хранить свое внутреннее состояние `expand`.
2. или в текущем состоянии `expand` устанавливать значение для КАЖДОГО отрисованного компонента Segment

```js
export default function TaskList(){

    const[data, setData] = useState([]);
    const[expand, setExpand] = useState(false); //Ошибка здесь, общий стейт для всех .segment 

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/dash/task_list')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => setData(json));

    },[]);
    console.log(data)
    return(
        <div className='segments'>
                {
                    data.map((task, index) => (
                        <div onClick={() => setExpand(!expand)} className={`segment ${expand ? 'active' : ''}`}>
                            <a className='header'>{task.task_id}</a>
                            <div className='description'>{task.event_time}</div>
                        </div>
                    ))
                }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде переменная состояния `expand` используется для вычисления атрибута `className` для всех тегов `div`, создаваемых функцией `map`.

Поэтому для каждого тега `div` должна быть определена отдельная переменная, вместо общей переменной `expand`.